# XVFB and Selenium on EC2 - Unable to view Chrome UI on VNC Viewer

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jenkins, aws, xvfb

My Selenium headless tests are triggered from Jenkins server and run in EC2-Ubuntu.  I want to view the test live on Chrome so I installed Xvfb plugin on Jenkins.

On EC2 I installed Xvfb. When I start executing the build, my test starts execution  and I see below logs:

```
Xvfb  /usr/bin/Xvfb :1 -fbdir /var/lib/jenkins/xvfb-27-..fbdir13700092919317283985
Parsing POMs
Established TCP socket on 30810
```

and I see the test is running successfully.

Now I do SSH to EC2 from Mac terminal by

```
ssh -L 5901:localhost:5901 qa_user@10.113.x.xxx
```

Then I execute:

```
qa_user@jenkins-it:~$ export DISPLAY=: 30810 (Port number from Jenkins logs above)
qa_user@jenkins-it:~$ vncserver "$DISPLAY" -geometry 1280x1024
```

New 'X' desktop is jenkins-it: 30810

Starting applications specified in `/home/qa_user/.vnc/xstartup`
Log file is `/home/qa_user/.vnc/jenkins-it: 30810.log`

```
qa_user@jenkins-it:~$ x11vnc --listen 0.0.0.0 -rfbport 5901 -display : 30810
```

This starts XVFB and I see:

[image: Display when XVFB starts]

Now when I connect from Mac to localhost:5901 from VNCviewer, I am taken to Ubuntu desktop.

[image: Ubuntu desktop via VNCviewer]

But I don't see chrome opening up even though the test is running and I see test logs on Jenkins.

I am also able to use Chrome via VncViewer.
[image: Using Chorme manually via VNCViewer]

What am I missing here?
I tried many Xvfb set up instructions and has been trying to get this right since a month now. Here are few questions I asked:

[Looking for a solution to run selenium tests on EC2 with GUI](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/45376/looking-for-a-solution-to-run-selenium-tests-on-ec2-with-gui/45380#45380)

Long way till here and now Stackoverflow is my last resort. Please help.

Comment: Headless means you cannot see UI. , Try doing the same with non headless mode and verify whether you can see chrome opening

Comment: I get below error if I remove options.addArguments("--headless"); from my code. 

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist) (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'

Comment: options.addArguments("--no-sandbox") try adding this

Comment: options.merge(capabilities);options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("enable-automation");
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); 
options.addArguments("--disable-browser-side-navigation");
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); 

No sandbox is already added. This is my current code.

Comment: options.addArgument("--remote-debugging-port=9222") try this

Comment: Can you please also mention the reason when you ask to try a step? I don't understand why remote-debugging is required.

Comment: @Aftal there will be many reason something is not working you have to debug and pin point it . As I don't access to your system the only thing I can suggest is to try using different solution . Once a solution works we can back trace to actual issue .

Comment: @PDHide, Tried remote-debugging, it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to this myself. For anyone who's having the same issue:

What I did wrong was I used  `driver = new ChromeDriver(options);` in my code instead of `driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://my.aws.ip:4444/wd/hub"), options);`

After making this change, I downloaded selenium-server-standalone.jar to in EC2.

Then, before starting the test, I did ssh -X qa_user@my.aws.ip to EC2 and executed:

```
Xvfb :99 -ac -screen 0 1280x1024x24 &
export DISPLAY=:99
java -jar /home/qa_user/Selenium/selenium-server-standalone.jar
```

Now, execute the test, in parallel I opened a new terminal and did:

`ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900 qa_user@my.aws.ip`

Once the screen was set, I did:

```
x11vnc -xkb -noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage -display :99 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0  -rfbport 5900
```

Next, open VNC viewer, connect to localhost:5900 and you'll see Chrome execution.

Later you can move all this to Jenkins pre-build execute shell if required :)

More details on my latest answer: [XVFB on Jenkins connecting to wrong display. Display shows black screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63935935/xvfb-on-jenkins-connecting-to-wrong-display-display-shows-black-screen).